# events.chart y lab text size

Tags: r, charts, axis, hmisc

Hi I have the following events.chart from the Hmisc package.

```
    event.chart(events,
    subset.c = c('D2BMET','T2Fail','Cens','zero'),
    x.lab = 'Progression Time for Breast Cancer Patients (months)',
    y.lab = 'Subjects (sorted by time to 1st Brain Metastasis)',
    y.idlabels = 'Pt', 
    titl = 'Breast Cancer Brain Metastasis Events Chart',
    point.pch = c(1,2,17,124), point.cex = c(1,1,1,1),
    legend.plot = TRUE, legend.location = 'i', legend.cex = 1,
    legend.point.text = c('Time to 1st Brain Metastasis', 'Last Followup', 'Death'),
    x.julian = TRUE,
    legend.bty='o', legend.point.at = list(c(400,400), c(14,14)))
```

I tried using the

```
    axis(2,cex.axis= 0.5)
```

to make the y-axis text smaller, but nothing happens.  Doing

```
    axis(1,cex.axis= 0.5)
```

makes the x-axis text smaller, but nothing seems to work on the y-axis.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: Your example is not reproducible.  What is events?

Answer (score 0):

With no test set, will instead suggest you read the help page more carefully with particular attention to:

"y.axis:

character string specifying whether program will control labelling of y-axis (with argument "auto"), or if user will control labelling (with argument "custom"). If "custom" is chosen, user must specify location and text of labels using y.axis.custom.at and y.axis.custom.labels arguments, respectively, listed below. This argument will not be utilized if y.idlabels is specified."

So with your choice to set `y.idlabels = "Pt"` you are giving up further control possibilities. It turns out that even setting `y.axis="custom"` that there is still not the opportunity to change the y.axis cex.axis. I discovered this after reviewing into the code. So you will need to hack the code. It's very well organized and you have the option of either adding a parameter or hard-coding a one-time change.